# Determine if the network path targeted by a shortcut is a folder or an archive in C#

Tags: c#, .net, shell, directory, archive

I'm trying to determine if the path targeted by a shortcut on Windows is a folder. Let's say I have a **test.lnk** file on my Desktop which points to the **R:\test** folder located on a network location. If I also have a shortcut that points to the **R:\test.zip** archive, I would not want this file to appear in my view.

I currently have the following code which correctly achieves this requirement:

```
Shell variable = (Shell)Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000")));
FolderItem variable1 = variable.NameSpace(directoryName).ParseName(fileName);
if (variable1 != null)
{
    var shellObject = (ShellLinkObject)variable1.GetLink;
    var isShortcutAFolder = shellObject.Target.IsFolder && shellObject.Target.Type == "File folder";
    // ...
}
```

The issue with this approach is that the **shellObject.Target.Type** property is of type **string** and its value depends on the language the user has on their machine. The reason I check this property in addition to the **IsFolder** property of the Target is that archive files (such as .zip and .rar) also have their IsFolder value as **true** and I do not wish to show such files as directories.

With this said, is there another property I can use of the FolderItem object or some cast that I can make to determine if the target path is actually a **file folder**?

I do not wish to use the **File.GetAttributes** or **Directory.Exists** methods as these result in degraded performance if the network location is offline or inaccessible.

Comment: `Directory.Exists` is the canonical way to do this. Maybe check if the network share is connected before calling it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this can be achieved in a generic mather? I.e. - given a certain path, determine if the network location is accessible.

Comment: Send a `Ping` to `new Uri(yourUNCpath).Host`